# Can't login to domain users after enroll successfully Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, login, active-directory

I'm working on ubuntu 22.04.
I installed all the required packages and enroll successfully to my domain.
my dc is on Windows server 2008 r2.
when I'm trying to login to any domain user after I'm entering the user name and password, I get this error "system error".